# Can BizTalk be used to fetch data from a dynamic URL?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I see that BizTalk has support for consuming web services [Tutorial 5: Invoking a REST Interface Using BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/tutorial-5-invoking-a-rest-interface-using-biztalk-server) (learn.microsoft.com)

There is a website like `https://thesite.com/12345/20200815/data.csv` . The part that is 20200815 changes every day. Can BizTalk download data from such a source using the web service consumption feature with the date part changed every day?

Comment: Yes you can, what are you having difficulty with?  You have tagged it with BizTalk 2010, the WCF-WebHTTP (REST) adapter doesn't exist in BizTalk 2010, although there is an open source version available.

Comment: Difficulty is in changing the date part of the URL. Need to understand whether that is possible and if so, how?

Comment: I made a minor correction to the URL mapping in my answer, as it still had Date= which came from a query string setup, which is not needed for your scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution I would do and have done in BizTalk 2013 R2 up.  However it might be slightly different with the Open Source Web [Rest adapter for BizTalk 2010](https://github.com/wmmihaa/REST-Start-Kit-for-BizTalk)

1. Have SQL polling receive location that runs a stored procedure that returns the date. An alternative is a schedule adapter and a map that sets the date.
2. Promote that date field in the SQL polling schema
3. Have a WCF-WebHttp send port where you have the date in the HTTP Method and URL mapping
4. Use the Variable Mapping to set that Date variable

HTTP Method and URL mapping

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>  
   <Operation Method="GET" Url="/12345/{Date}/data.csv" />  
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

Variable Mappping

[image]